# How to stop video replay in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video, silverlight-plugin

Ive used silverlight player in our internal builds and one issue we are facing is that the video is automatically replaying as soon as its over.

Does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hook up the MediaEnded event and stop the video when it finishes.

```
private void player_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    player.Stop();            
}
```